# React Native Avatar won't center align over text

Tags: css, react-native, avatar, touchableopacity

I have an avatar and a text field inside a `TouchableOpacity`. I need both the avatar and the text to be center inside the `TouchableOpacity` and I need the avatar on one row and the text underneath every time even on screen resize.

The below code will place the avatar and the text side by side, and that is not correct:

```js
<View>
  <TouchableOpacity>
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
      }}
    >
      <Avatar size={22} rounded source={{ uri: item1.avatarUrl2 }} />
      <Text
        style={{
          color: COLORS.purple_dark,
          fontSize: 12,
          textAlign: "center",
        }}
      >
        **The title of my Avatar will go Here**
      </Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Comment: `flexDirection: 'row'` ? delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to keep Avatar in one row and the text just below it, then you need to comment out `flexDirection: "row"` from your code as by default in React components are placed in column. Or you can pass `flexDirection: "column"`.

```
<View>
  <TouchableOpacity>
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: "row", // comment it out or pass "column"
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
      }}
    >
      <Avatar size={22} rounded source={{ uri: item1.avatarUrl2 }} />
      <Text
        style={{
          color: COLORS.purple_dark,
          fontSize: 12,
          textAlign: "center",
        }}
      >
        **The title of my Avatar will go Here**
      </Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

This will keep the components vertically aligned.

[image]